# Can I delete AndroidStudio2.3 files after updating AndroidStudio to 3.0 version?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, memory

I was cleaning my system from unused application then I found that `c:\user\mysystem\AndroidStudio2.3` ,  `c:\user\mysystem\AndroidStudio3.0` files are in my system while I updated the Android Studio two months ago to 3.0 version. So can I delete `c:\user\mysystem\AndroidStudio2.3` this file?

Other then that there are two another folders are also available occupying  the system memory  `c:\user\mysystem\.android` and `c:\Android`.

This `c:\Android` folder have the `SDK` and this folder `c:\user\mysystem\.android` is for what? Can I delete it also?

Comment: why don't you just try that? Just backup them, and then check if everything works.

Comment: You can delete it, but after deleting you will have to download all DSK and stuff again

Comment: what is DSK can you please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the older version's folder of android studio  `c:\user\mysystem\AndroidStudio2.3` and nothing goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

While in the `c:\user\mysystem\.android` contain all cache data and all the emulator data in this folder while deleting this folder. This deletes all your cache and the emulator data. But when you running `Android Studio` it regenerates this folder automatically and contains all the cache data. And if you have to use the emulator you have to download it again manually.